# Apache POI XSSF header not created

Tags: coldfusion, apache-poi, coldfusion-10

As I experiment with xlsx creation, I'm stuck on creating headers. I'm able to create a file with rows and merged cells, but headers never seem to work. Here's what I have:

```
var WorkBook = CreateObject( 
    "java",
    "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook"
).Init();

var Sheet = WorkBook.CreateSheet(
    JavaCast( "string", 'my sheetname' )
);

// create the default header if it doesn't exist
var header = sheet.getHeader(); // have also tried getEvenHeader() and getOddHeader()

header.setText('&LLeft Section');
// have also tried the following:
//header.setLeft('left header');
//header.setCenter('CENTER');
//header.setRight('right header');

// open the file stream
var FileOutputStream = CreateObject(
    "java",
    "java.io.FileOutputStream"
).Init(
    JavaCast( "string", filename )
);

// Write the workbook data to the file stream.
WorkBook.Write( 
    FileOutputStream 
);

// Close the file output stream.
FileOutputStream.Close();
```

When I run this code, no errors are thrown. The file is created and can be opened without throwing any errors, but no headers appear. And like I said, if I create rows/cells instead of a header, those are created correctly. What am I missing?

EDIT:
As Leigh points out below, headers/footers have a different meaning in Excel than how I was thinking of them (as in PDFs). I got thrown off by the way adding a header in Excel shows it above the first row, and thought that adding one through POI would do the same thing.

Comment: Silly question, but how are you verifying the headers are not present? They should only be present when printing (or in print preview).  FWIW, the code above worked fine for me w/CF11, after populating at least one cell, (ie so there was something to print).

Comment: What do you mean by "Header"? The first row in the sheet? The print header? Something else?

Comment: @Leigh Hmmmm..... I thought they should be showing because when I insert a  header in Excel, it does appear, above the first row. I had the (evidently wrong) assumption that if I created a header programatically it would appear the same way. So in Excel, headers/footers are strictly for use when printing? I guess that makes sense now that I think about it. File that under D'oh!!!

Comment: And I guess that since I've been spending a good amount of time working on PDF exports, where headers and footers have a different meaning entirely, that I got fixated on that model.

Comment: Yes, [headers and footers have a different meaning in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Headers-and-footers-in-a-worksheet-CAE2A88C-64A7-42AB-96A4-28D2FC16AD31) ;-) *"...Headers and footers are not displayed on the worksheet in Normal view — they are displayed only in Page Layout view and on the printed pages."*

Comment: @Leigh, feel free to add your answer and I'll give you the points ;-)

Comment: Will do.  Since I vaguely recall having a similar thought when I first used them, I will write it up in case it helps someone else :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Promoted from comments, in case the answer is helpful for the next guy)

Silly question, but how are you verifying the headers are not present? In Excel, [headers and footers should only be visible when printing (or in print preview mode)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Headers-and-footers-in-a-worksheet-CAE2A88C-64A7-42AB-96A4-28D2FC16AD31).

> ...Headers and footers are not displayed on the worksheet in Normal
>   view — they are displayed only in Page Layout view and on the printed
>   pages.

FWIW, the code works fine for me under CF10 and 11, after I populated at least one cell (so there was something to print).

[**Runnable Example on trycf.com**](http://trycf.com/gist/011e3494c818f8c63c29b6e28dddfec3/acf?theme=monokai)

```
<cfscript>
    workBook = CreateObject( "java", "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook").Init();
    sheet = WorkBook.CreateSheet( JavaCast( "string", 'my sheetname' ) );
    header = sheet.getHeader(); // have also tried getEvenHeader() and getOddHeader()
    header.setText('&LLeft Section');
    // add some data so there is something to print
    sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("sample value");
    // Using binary stream because trycf.com does not support files for security reasons
    baos = createObject("java", "java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream").init();
    // Write the workbook data to the binary stream
    workBook.write( baos );
    baos.close();
</cfscript>

<!--- CF10 lacks support for script version of cfcontent --->
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    variable="#baos.toByteArray()#">
```